# Which plugin could minify the Dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

Which plugin could minify the Dashboard? Are W3 Total Cache and Better Wordpress Minify complatible with each other?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a minify plugin for scripts in the wp-admin area?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in minifying my Admin area! :) (for real)

Comment: I'm interested to see if there are any options for this as I would find it useful too.

Comment: I am atm looking into the code of W3 Total Cache. Could you help me, please for a moment? /w3-total-cache/lib/W3/Plugin/Minify.php line 88. What do you think? :D [UPDATE:] Look 888-892! Just comment it out! Could it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Author of W3 Total Cache Better Wordpress Minify and W3 Total Cache are Not compatible with each-other due to the fact that they are rpetty much based on the same code.

OK, after about 20 mins of searching and trying, the solution is Pretty easy.
Of course it's a "solution" only if you are using W3 Total Cache.
You'll have to enable the minification feature first, without that your pages won't be minified of course.

**[IMPORTANT:]**

Please Disable *Inline JS Minification* under your Minify settings and Disable *Line break removal* under the Javascript tab on the Minify page, because if you don't your Wordpress Dashboard may misfunction.

So first, go into your preferred code editor and edit the following two files:

```
wp-content\plugins\w3-total-cache\lib\W3\Plugin\TotalCache.php
```

search for: `function can_ob()`
'ob' is not for Object Cache, it is for *Check if we can do modify contents* as the plugin's author noted above the function
below that just modify the lines to

```
if (defined('WP_ADMIN')) {
            return true;
}
```

after that you have to modify the following file:

```
wp-content\plugins\w3-total-cache\lib\W3\Plugin\Minify.php
```

search for: `function can_minify()`
modify the lines to

```
if (defined('WP_ADMIN')) {
            //$this->minify_reject_reason = 'wp-admin';//comment out this line
            return true;
}
```

Comment: editing plugin files is never a good idea, you'll lose your changes on an update.

Comment: gimme a sec then

Comment: `function enable_the_minification_of_admin_pages() {
 if (defined('WP_ADMIN')) {
            $this->minify_reject_reason = '';
            return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'can_minify', 'enable_the_minification_of_admin_pages' );
add_filter( 'can_ob', 'enable_the_minification_of_admin_pages' );` Am I doing something wrong here? I don't believe that there is another way.

Comment: Don't add code in comments, it is unreadable, and most people ignore comments. You should file an [edit] and post the code inside your answer. :-)

Comment: This is great, can you please edit your answer and add the function?

Comment: Ahhh, the function is Not Working at all, because the line below 'WP_ADMIN' returns false, you cannot add a filter in that way, because it won't be executed anyway

Comment: @LZLo So there is no way to hook into this and the only option is to edit the core files?

Comment: I see no available options, just look into those php files and you will know what I am talking about